# Forecasting - accuracy vs. size trade off?

Tags: forecasting

I am new to forecasting. Occasionally, I have to face the following problem. I have data set A. Each element in this set has n features and I need to build classification model using this data set (assume k - classification categories).

Building model on the whole data set occasionally yields poor results, so I am routinely asked to find a subset of set A, such that quality of forecast is significantly better. Or sometimes I am asked to forecast fewer than k categories, but again with much better precision. Hence I am facing trade off quality of forecast vs. size of data set and number of categories.

Does anybody know if this trade off has standard name and what are known approaches to solving it? Ranking categories in term of forecastability? Generating subsets of the main set and ordering them in terms of forecastability?